# Choice for HEAVY blacksmith table

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, control-engineering, solid-mechanics

I have an old 7,000 lb. blacksmith table (I had it weighed at truck stop). Similar to the one this man has:
[image]

Sorry for the size of the pic.

I need to lift one end the way he is doing and I have a farm jack that is capable of doing it. The problem the table top is too high for the farm jack to reach. My shop floor is not fully level so when I put something with a wide enough base to put the farm jack on; everything becomes wobbly. Using the farm jack alone is fine but I don't feel safe putting something under the farm jack to make it reach the height of the tabletop.

Under the tabletop is a 5in.x5in. solid square steel brace that is welded between the legs (brace is 52in. in length). When I got the table the previous owner told me that those braces were solid steel square bars. Also the previous owner, or whoever welded the braces in, cared enough to engrave a warning on these braces that stated DO NOT REMOVE.

Now I would just jack one side of the table from under the steel brace but the underside of the braces is not fully flat and the farm jack's claw does not fit securely and eventually slides out after a few pumps. (I guess the previous owner used these when working on stuff)

Each brace has a total of 6 holes:
2 holes are in the center and aligned vertically (2-1/2in. on top of each other)
2 holes are on each end and are 40in. apart (on each end the 2 holes are aligned horizontally 3in. between them).

I only have some thin steel in my shop nothing that would be suitable for this.

When I came to the site I saw some guy post a question that was similar to what I need (I was laughing so hard because it sounded almost dead on what I was going to ask) but the answer he got wasn't suitable for me.

Seeing that I do have 4x4's (wood) laying around and A LOT of grade 8 bolts. I am thinking of trying what that guy did or is planning on doing (he didn't update his post). I am going to bolt the 4x4 to the brace and the farm jack's claw will fit securely under the 4x4 and I can lift one end of the table like the man is doing in the picture.

Should I bolt the 4x4 to the 2 center vertical holes?...meaning I cut the 4x4 at 5in. (the width of the brace) and make the 2 vertical holes align with the 2 vertical holes in the brace. The cut ends of the 4x4 will be facing up and down; the smooth ends of the 4x4 will be facing left and right.

Or

Should I bolt the 4x4 length wise?...meaning I cut the 4x4 at 40in. (the length of the brace) and make the 2 holes on each side (4 in total) and bolt it to the brace. The cut ends of the 4x4 will be facing left and right; the smooth ends will be facing up and down.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a link to the "other guy" post?

Comment: Make a tripod and secure the legs to each other so they don't spread - stable solution.

Comment: This 5000# table from 'The Essential Craftsman https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBRQjT8UAGs ?